# Отрицательное значение margin-top, или как правильно

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

В примере кода, при нажатии кнопки *'Показать'* получил нужное мне расположение оранжевого дива (3) по отношению к диву (1), т.е. чуть ниже верхней границы дива (1).

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Но если контент в дивах 1, или 2 их растянет вниз, то и нужное мне расположение дива_3 съедет. В примере кода див (3) идет после первых двух. Если сделать его первым :

```
<div id="v" style="display:none; margin-top:-255px; margin-left:12px;"> 3</div>

<div style="width:350px; height:125px; background-color:silver;"> 1</div>
<div style="width:350px; height:125px; background-color:grey;"> 2</div>

<input type="button" value="Показать" style="width:173px;" onclick="f1()">
<input type="button" value="Скрыть" style="width:173px;" onclick="f2()">
```

то как правильно указать стили, чтобы не зависеть от меняющихся высот дивов 2 и 3 ?
Ну и отрицательный margin-top слышал, что делать не правильно. Поправьте, пожалуйста.

---

Пример кода :

```js
function f1() {
 // Показать
    document.getElementById('v').style.display = 'block';
}
function f2() {
 // Скрыть
 document.getElementById('v').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#v {
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    width: 180px;
    height:180px;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:350px; height:125px; background-color:silver;"> 1</div>
<div style="width:350px; height:125px; background-color:grey;"> 2</div>

<input type="button" value="Показать" style="width:173px;" onclick="f1()">
<input type="button" value="Скрыть" style="width:173px;" onclick="f2()">

<div id="v" style="display:none; margin-top:-255px; margin-left:12px;"> 3</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/f55qyx4z/

Comment: да, круто, перевариваю Ваш пример решения ...

Comment: @soledar10, отлично работает Ваш код, большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы третий блок не зависел от высоты первого блока, можно:

1. назначить первому блоку относительное позиционирование;
2. третий блок позиционировать абсолютно и поместить его внутрь первого блока.

Тогда положение третьего блока будет рассчитываться относительно границ его родителя. Далее `top`, `left` и `transform` по вкусу:

- `top: 15px;` = 15 пикселей ниже верхней границы первого блока
- `left: 15px;` = 15 пикселей от левого края

```js
COLLECTION_V3 = document.getElementsByClassName('v3');

function f1() {
    // Показать
    for (var i = 0; i < COLLECTION_V3.length; i++) {
        COLLECTION_V3[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
function f2() {
    // Скрыть
    for (var i = 0; i < COLLECTION_V3.length; i++) {
        COLLECTION_V3[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
.v1, .v2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px;
  min-height: 125px;
}
.v1 { background: silver; }
.v2 { background: grey; }
.v3 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px; 
  /*
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  */
  z-index:5;
  width: 180px;
  height:180px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="v1">1 <div class="v3">3</div></div>
<div class="v2">2 </div>

<div class="v1">1 <br>1 <br>1 <br>1 <br>1 <br>1 <br>1 <br>1 <br>1 <br>1 <br>1 <br>1 <div class="v3">3</div></div>
<div class="v2">2 </div>

<input type="button" value="Показать" style="width:173px;" onclick="f1()">
<input type="button" value="Скрыть" style="width:173px;" onclick="f2()">
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, нужно без jquery ...

Comment: @Alex Тут  jQuery только нажатия на кнопки обрабатывает. Можно и без него. Суть ответа от этого не меняется.

Comment: @Alex Убрал jQuery из ответа.

Comment: вот изменил в Вашем примере высоту дивов 1 и 2 со 125px на 225px и получил уже на выходе див_3 не в прежнем положении, а ниже. А нужно, чтобы этот оранжевый див_3 всегда появлялся в одном месте, при изменении высоты дивов 1 и 2.

Comment: @Alex В моём примере третий блок позиционируется относительно границы между первым и вторым блоками. Увеличилась высота - сдвинулась граница между блоками и сдвинулся третий блок. Можно задать ему другое позиционирование. Вам какое нужно?

Comment: первая моя картинка показывает желанное расположение дива 3 по отношению к первым двум, - "т.е. чуть ниже верхней границы дива (1)".

Comment: @Alex Насколько ниже? На 10 пикселей? На 10 процентов высоты первого блока? На 10% высоты третьего блока? Нужна точная инструкция.

Comment: этот отступ я получил так : margin-top:-255px; там приведен в моем примере весь код, сорри, если запутал ...

Comment: @Alex Если увеличить высоту первого блока, третий должен остаться  на прежнем месте или должен сместиться пропорционально изменению высоты?

Comment: пусть будет на 15px ниже верхней границы блока_1, например.

Comment: третий блок должен оставаться на месте ...

Comment: Собственно исходно писал -- "А нужно, чтобы этот оранжевый див_3 всегда появлялся в одном месте, при изменении высоты дивов 1 и 2."

Comment: @Alex Пропустил эту фразу, извините. Изменил свой ответ под ваши условия. Проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: может я где-то косячу, но у меня опять в Вашем новом примере при 125 пикселях на первом и втором диве имею один отступ у дива_3, а при увеличении со 125 на 225 пикселей, - этот отступ тоже увеличился, а нужно , чтобы был 'заморожен' ... возьму минут 30 паузу ... кстати, в примере, который привел выше @soledar10, - работает как надо ...

Comment: @Alex Обратите внимание, что я переместил третий блок из второго в первый. Если проблемы сохранятся, дайте ссылку на фидл.

Comment: Всё чётко работает и как нужно, большое спасибо.